# Child controller $scope property changes not updating for parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new to angularjs and scopes, but I'm having trouble with scope values changed in child controllers not affecting the parent value properly.

One example:

I have a child controller that watches for changes in a textarea. When they occur, I set a boolean flag to indicate the document has unsaved changes.

```
editor.on('input propertychange', function(){
   $scope.unsaved = true;
}).focus();
```

However, this never seems to filter up to the parent scope. My root template has an anchor:

```
<a ng-class="{'active': unsaved}" ...
```

The class is set properly on load, but never changes when `$scope.unsaved` does.

If I set `$scope.$parent.unsaved`, it will only change the template the second time the input event fires.

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$apply();` after setting the variable?

Comment: Yes, all I get is an error "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Can you make a plunkr really quickly so we can see it run?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is instead of having

```
editor.on('input propertychange', function(){
$scope.unsaved = true;
}).focus();
```

You could just add a `ng-change` event:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a" ng-change="madeChange()"/>
```

And add a new method in your `scope`:

```
$scope.madeChange = function() {
    $scope.saved = false;
}
```

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bUI2AFshnYnSWVrHmqOb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I've made an working example with two-way databinding between controllers and purely in angularjs, no 3rd party code

http://plnkr.co/edit/4DZAncKYS0XvTB7Z4YEQ?p=preview